# Switching users in PgAdmin

Tags: logins, pgadmin, connections

I'm looking for a way to enable switching between users in pgAdmin 4. I'm aware of the possibilty to change user from the properties-dialog before connecting. However this isn't useful when I'm already logged in, since it seems impossible to logout and get permission to change user in the properites-dialog.

Anyone have a solution for this? Is it possible having mutiple connections instead, one per user?

Comment: [set role](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-role.html)?

Comment: Didn't know about that one, should work thanks!